# Local storage being overwritten with new data

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

Hello guys I made a history page so the user can look at their past search history and so I used localstorage. On the history page, I am trying to render data that stays there and isn't changed when I go to search the api again. Instead I want it to keep adding data to the page. I was thinking the data would just keep being added to the new array in local storage but it overwrites the existing data with new data. Ive made an attempt to prevent this but I am stuck.
Here is my code of all of my pages

**Search page**

```
export default function SearchPage(props) {
        // creating state to fetch the api
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

    
    // this is my function to monitor the words that are put into the input so these keywords that only matches specific data
    // in the api and so one the data is fetched it renders the topic related to that keyword 
    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        setSearch(event.target.value)
    }


    const handleSubmit = (event) => {       
        event.preventDefault();
            // this is where I bring my useState variable to monitor the state of the key words in order to
            // target specific data from the api    
        let url = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=${search}`; 
        axios
        .get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            const result = response.data.hits;
            // this pushes the data fetched from the api to the results page using history
            props.history?.push ({
                pathname: '/results', 
                state: result,
            });
        })
        // catching any errors to let me know if there is something going on in the .then function
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            console.log('Error while fetching data!')
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="search-form-container">
                {/* my form in where I search data by keywords */}
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
                    <input type='text' placeholder="search" onChange={handleSearch} value={search}/>
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <hr/>
                <Link to="/history">Your Search History</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Results page**

```
export default function ResultsPage(props) {
    console.log(props)
    // the variable declared below is where I am bringing in the data through history from the api.
    const data = props.history.location.state;

    
        let storedData = localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))
        console.log(storedData)


    // being that I am using history, I can map through the array of objects on the results page as shown below and then render it
    const hitList = data.map((data, idx) => {
        return (
            <ul key={idx}>
                <div>
                  <li> Author: {data.author}</li> 
                  <li>Story Title: {data.story_title}</li> 
                  <li>Comment: {data.comment_text}</li>  
                  <li>Created on: {data.created_at}</li>  
                  <li></li>  
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </ul>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to='/'><h1>Search</h1></Link> 
            <Link to='/history'><h1>Your History</h1></Link>
            {/* In order for me to show my data I first had to map through the array of objects and then put the variable "hitlist" in the return */}
            <h3>{hitList}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**History page**

```
export default function SearchHistoryPage(item) {
        
        const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        storedData.push(item);
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(storedData));
        console.log(storedData);                                    

        const searchHistory = storedData.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
                <ul key={idx}>
                  <li> Author: {data.author}</li> 
                  <li>Story Title: {data.story_title}</li> 
                  <li>Comment: {data.comment_text}</li>  
                  <li>Created on: {data.created_at}</li>  
                </ul>
            )
        })

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{searchHistory}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **Results page**, you are overwriting your localStorage 'data' key with **only the results fetched from Search page**.

What you can do is to fetch your "history" (localStorage 'data') before you push the new results **in your Results page, and not in your History page** as so:

In **Results page**:

```
const data = props.history.location.state;

// ADD THESE 2 LINEs
const historicData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
historicData.push(data)

// Store "historicData" instead of "data"
// let storedData = localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))
let storedData = localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(historicData))

console.log(storedData)
```

In **History page**:

```
// Just use localStorage 'data'. 
// Do not modify anything in History page since you are not taking any actions here. 
const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
storedData.push(item);
// localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(storedData)); <-- REMOVE
// console.log(storedData); <-- REMOVE
```

Comment: Thanks but two issues arrived in this solution. 1. When I delete all of my local storage and try to add new data it say cannot push property of null because Im not longer setting item first before I get data on results page. 2.When the new data is added to the existing data, it creates a nested array and it just keeps nesting the array each time I add new data to the local storage.

Comment: Issue 1 - You can simply put a conditional to avoid such errors. Issue 2 - That depends on how your data is structured. For my suggestion I assumed your data is a list of lists, and you are "fetch"ing a list (of search results). Both can be simply refined according to your needs (destructuring, etc.). I have focused and answered what you have originally asked - "overwrites the existing data with new data". The exact syntax and how to apply for your project is up to you.